# Strictly RAW, does Desna's Shooting Star add full Charisma bonus with Two-Weapon Fighting?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, two-weapon-fighting

Desna's Shooting Star is a [Divine Fighting Technique](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Divine%20Fighting%20Technique). Here is what it does:

> You can add your Charisma bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls when wielding a starknife. If you do so, you don’t modify attack rolls and damage rolls with your starknife with your Strength modifier, your Dexterity modifier (if you have Weapon Finesse), or any other ability score (if you have an ability that allows you to modify attack rolls and damage rolls with that ability score).

For comparison, here is another power that allows to use another Ability Score instead of Strength:

> **Finesse Training (Ex):** At 1st level, a rogue gains Weapon Finesse as a bonus feat. In addition, starting at 3rd level, she can select any one type of weapon that can be used with Weapon Finesse (such as rapiers or daggers). Once this choice is made, it cannot be changed. Whenever she makes a successful melee attack with the selected weapon, she adds her Dexterity modifier *instead* of her Strength modifier to the damage roll. If any effect would prevent the rogue from adding her Strength modifier to the damage roll, she does not add her Dexterity modifier. The rogue can select a second weapon at 11th level and a third at 19th level.

Because Desna's Shooting Star just adds Charisma and doesn't add Strength instead of replacing Charisma with Strength, I believe that it wouldn't be halved when using [Two-Weapon Fighting](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-fighting-combat/). Thus, if my Charisma is 22, I would hit for 1d4+6 with each of my Starknives, and I would hit for the same with one of those.

Is it correct under a strict RAW approach?

Comment: "You can add your Charisma bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls when wielding a starknife" -> Another consequence of reading this is as RAW that you don't add your Charisma to the attacks made _using_ the Starknife - you add your charisma to _all_ attack rolls and _all_ damage rolls made _while wielding_ it. That means that you can blast a fireball or bonk your enemies with a club while holding a starknife on your other hand and get the bonus anyway. More so, it's only the attacks made with the starknife that don't get the STR bonus. All other weapons still do.

Comment: @T.Sar Haven't thought about that, actually. It turns out to be even more OP now. Should definitely get a third hand for this.

Answer (score 11):

### By strict (and silly) RAW, yes.

But it is even worse than that.

In addition to the point you noted, there is also this:

> You can add your Charisma bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls when **wielding a starknife**.

Another consequence of reading this is as RAW that you don't add your Charisma to the attacks made using the Starknife - you add your charisma to all attack rolls and all damage rolls made while wielding it. That means that you can blast a fireball or bonk your enemies with a club while holding a starknife on your other hand and get the bonus anyway.

More so,

> If you do so, you don’t modify attack rolls and damage rolls with your starknife with your Strength modifier, your Dexterity modifier (if you have Weapon Finesse), or any other ability score (if you have an ability that allows you to modify attack rolls and damage rolls with that ability score).

It's only the attacks made with the starknife that don't get the STR/DEX bonus. All other weapons still do.

### Under a reasonable GM, probably no.

To me - and most other GMs, I believe - this feat looks a lot like it should work just as Finesse Training, and a such should use similar wording instead of the current raw-mess, replacing STR or DEX by Char for the damage and attack rolls made while *attacking with* a starknife, and nothing else.

Comment: Also, I guess it would not stack with Smite Evil, only the greater bonus would apply. Or would it actually stack?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy It would absolutely stack with Smite Evil in both readings. While the size of the bonus is the same (both are Cha-sized bonuses), the sources are different and thus they would stack. Keep in mind that Smite Evil doesn't modify an attack roll (as in, replaces what you use to roll), it gives you an untyped bonus to both attack and damage that happens to be CHA-Sized.

Comment: There is no definition of "To wield" that is "To hold." It is "To handle with skill and ease," or "To exercise effectively." This, to me, implies you *do* need to actually use the starknife.

Comment: @Jason_c_o [According to Merriam Webster, one of the meanings for "wield"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wield) is basically the same as "to handle", which means "to manage with the hands". Someone wielding a gun doesn't necessarily needs to be shooting with it - they just need to be holding it and have it ready to use. Same for a sword, broom, or starknife. In the same manner,

Comment: @T.Sar Actually, Paizo stated in the official FAQ that untyped bonuses equal to an ability score **don’t** stack, with some BS about it being a kind of bonus type sort of. You’re absolutely right that their answer is entirely without basis in the rules, but Paizo considers the FAQ an official rules source, and frequently uses it for stealth errata. And I believe they may have also addressed ability replacements on damage rolls and indicated that they continue to be multiplied by ½ or 1½ as appropriate—again without any actual support in the rules.

Comment: Holding a gun at your side is not wielding a gun. Same for a sword, broom, or starknife.

Comment: @Jason_c_o Just wield two weapons: a Starknife in your off-hand and a real weapon (e.g. a Scimitar) in your main hand. You don't even have to strike with the Starknife, like when you don't have the Two-Weapon Fighting Feat

Comment: @jason_c_o having a gun ready to shoot is wielding it, even of you don't shoot it at all. Having a blade ready to strike is wielding it, even if you don't stroke with it at all.

Comment: This may seem silly unless you consider the mechanic of the effect as coming from wielding the starknife in a dazzling style.

Comment: @candied_orange Maybe that's the case! Or maybe Desna just likes starknifes that much that let their users cheat things a bit. Hard to tell!